# Name of accessory to hold rope together?

Tags: outdoor, fence, construction, joinery

What's the name of this accessory that holds two pieces of rope together?

[image]

Comment: That type of splice is not very strong for a in line splice like that they work best to make a loop because the rope change direction 180 degrees increases the holding power. It would be best to watch a video on splicing rope , it will be stronger and look better in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link on how to splice rope?

Comment: Google:  braid / splice rope. u-tube has a quick 3 minute video this looks the best , I use a similar method for crab pots or when I break a tow rope but it. Is much quicker and looks like crap, but it is quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rope clamp.  A rope crimping sleeve also performs the same task.